# Error: can't find 'dust' module when rendering dust templates on node.js

Tags: node.js, express, dust.js

I'm starting with the boilerplate code express generates for me. I'm requiring `dustjs-linkedin` and compiling some simple templates in `app.js` like so:

```
var dust = require('dustjs-linkedin');...

app.set('view engine', 'dust');...

var compiled = dust.compile("Hello {name}!","intro");
// add into dust.cache manually
dust.loadSource(compiled);
console.log(dust.cache);

dust.render("intro", {name: "Fred"}, function(err, out) {
  if(err){console.log(err)}
  console.log(out);
});
```

This is all works well and I see the HTML outputted in my terminal. Its only when I try and do the same thing from within a route when I start getting this error:

`GET / 500 11.607 ms - 904`
`Error: Cannot find module 'dust'`

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  var compiled = dust.compile("Hello {name}!", "intro");
  dust.loadSource(compiled)
  dust.render("intro", {name: "Fred"}, function(err, out) {
    console.log(out);
    res.send(out);
    res.close();
  });
});
```

This is all within `app.js`, only it works outside of a route, but not when I move it into a route callback. Does anyone know why it can't find 'dust'? I've required it and it should be visible from within the callback right?

Thanks for any help!

**Edit 1**
As per the comment below, 'dust' is getting required somewhere. I'm not doing it in my code; my guess is that Express is doing it behind the scenes because my templates have '.dust' file ending. I just tried deleting all my templates (wasn't using them anyways) and now I just get this error:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory
```

All I want is to see the output: "Hello Fred"

**Edit 2: I think I found what was wrong**

Everything **Interrobang** posted is correct. The problem, I think, was this middleware block that was generated for me by express-generator:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

So for every request, this middleware would fire and throw an error. I'm not 100% sure what its doing but if I comment it out, everything works. My secondary question now, if I may have one, is what exactly is going on and why is it set for all requests?

Comment: Im using: dustjs-linkedin@2.6.1 and express@4.12.3

Comment: That error doesn't mean `dust` isn't defined-- it means that a `require` call is failing. Something is calling `require('dust')` somewhere in your code.

Comment: I'm not requiring dust in my code but I found something in the Express docs: `By default, Express will require() the engine based on the file extension. For example, if you try to render a “foo.jade” file, Express invokes the following internally, and caches the require() on subsequent calls to increase performance.
app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express);`  My views do have a dust file extension, perhaps Express is requiring dust? But then again... haven't even tried to render a dust template yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting the `view engine` to `dust`, but you haven't registered an engine with Express to tell it how to render Dust-- and Express can't do it by default.

Consider using [`consolidate`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/consolidate), [`hoffman`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hoffman), or [`adaro`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adaro) (among others) as your Dust rendering engine for Express.

Here's a complete example using consolidate. I have tested and this works on my machine.

```
var express = require('express'),
    cons = require('consolidate'),
    app = express();

// assign the dust engine to .dust files 
app.engine('dust', cons.dust);

// set .dust as the default extension 
app.set('view engine', 'dust');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { name: 'Interrobang' });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Visit http://localhost:3000 woo!');
});
```

Alternatively, simply remove the `view engine` line from your code. You're not using Express to do the rendering, so Express doesn't even need to know.

Here's a very simple example without any view engine that I've tested to work. Your Dust templates go in a folder called `views`.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    express = require('express'),

    dust = require('dustjs-helpers');

dust.config.whitespace = true;

dust.onLoad = function(tmpl, cb) {
  fs.readFile(path.join('./views', path.resolve('/', tmpl + '.dust')),
              { encoding: 'utf8' }, cb);
};

var app = express();
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  dust.stream("hello", { "world": "World!" }).pipe(res);
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Visit http://localhost:3000 woo!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just tried to remove the `view engine` line but ended up with this error: `Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.`. So I'm going with `consolidate`. My very simple template now loads, but the object I pass to `res.render` doesn't seem to form the context of the template. `{@contextDump}` doesn't return anything. Anything off the top of your head that I could try?

Comment: If `{@contextDump}` doesn't return anything, are you sure you have `dustjs-helpers` installed? I added a very simple example to my answer that I know works, to help you debug. Try setting `dust.debugLevel = "DEBUG"` to see any Dust issues dumped to console.

Comment: You're right. `{@contextDump}` didn't work b/c I didn't have `dustjs-helpers` installed. After installing it, I'm getting more descriptive errors now. The template that I'm rendering is literally as simple as this: `foo{name}bar`. After this: `res.render("index", {name: "Fred"});`, I see **foobar** in the browser. The error is this: `[DUST:INFO] Cannot find the value for reference [{name}] in template [null]`. Also, I'm using **consolidate** for my view engine, although I appreciate your example demonstrating it working without any view engines.

Comment: I updated the first example (the consolidate example) with a full script that I ran on my machine. It worked as I'd expect, showing `fooInterrobangbar`

Comment: Ah yea when I replace my app.js with yours it DOES work. I must be doing something wrong somewhere. Anywho, Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you update your question with your app.js? We'll figure it out!

Comment: Hey thanks, I updated my question. Found that commenting out a bit of middleware solved the problem, but now am wondering about why exactly that is. My app.js is literally boilerplate + your consolidate example.

Comment: That's a 404 middleware, so it needs to be the last route defined-- after all your `app.get`s and such. Did you put it first?

Comment: Ohhhh I see. Yup I had my `get`s after that middleware. That explains why it kept trying to look up a template called `error`. Case closed! I really appreciated your help!!